# Validate file size and type in a multiple input

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, validation, input

i have 3 input file, i wanna make a javascript validation for 3 input file in one submit button form event onSubmit=""

```
<form action="step2_crud_dev.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="dataPribadi"  >
    <div>
    <input type="file" name="fUpload1" id="fileUpload1"/>
    <input type="file" name="fUpload2" id="fileUpload2"/>
    <input type="file" name="fUpload3" id="fileUpload3"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**EDITED CODE**
new code that working but, still proccess saving

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tbl_next').click(function(){
        //alert('hello');
        $('input[type="file"]').each(function(){
            var thisFile = $(this);
            var fileSize = thisFile[0].files[0].size;
            var fileType = thisFile[0].files[0].type;
            //alert(fileSize);

            if(fileSize>1048576){ //do something if file size more than 1 mb (1048576)
                alert(fileSize +" bites\n ukuran gambar terlalu besar");
                return false;
            }else{
                switch(fileType){
                    case 'image/png':
                    case 'image/gif':
                    case 'image/jpeg':
                    case 'image/pjpeg':
                        alert("Acceptable image file!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert('Unsupported File!');
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
        $('form#dataPribadi').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: __IDs must be unique in HTML__, Guys its __unique identifier__

Comment: wrap it up in a form element and then have a onSubmit function on it

Comment: i tried but it for by one validation or per file input at event onchange

Comment: @user3335420 have you tried the solution provided below?

Comment: @user3335420 have you changed the html? It don't have button with id 'tbl_next'.

Comment: Hope it can help somebody https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663160/jquery-validate-filesize-in-multidimensional-array-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change type of submit button to normal button and use `onclick` handler for it by giving a `id` as `upload`,

```
<form action="step2_crud_dev.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="dataPribadi"  >
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="fUpload1" id="fileUpload1"/>
        <input type="file" name="fUpload2" id="fileUpload2"/>
        <input type="file" name="fUpload3" id="fileUpload3"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="upload" value="upload" />
    </div>
</form>
```

and your click event handler should be,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#upload').click(function(){
        alert('hello');
        $('input[type="file"]').each(function(){
            var thisFile = $(this);
            var fileSize = thisFile[0].files[0].size;
            alert(fileSize);
        });
        $('form#dataPribadi').submit();
    });
});
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/msuL0yta/33/)

Comment: thanks it works for the function, i'll improve again

Comment: but i still need a lil help later, may be :D

Comment: Ohh, you can add to your question though. We are glad to help!

Comment: i already update the code (javascript) with new code that u give to me, but when its get false input (file too big) php code / saving proccess still go on. i already put "return false;" but its not working to stop the proccess.

Comment: it still go on, maybe because it each proses